# Wide variety of unambiguous constructors for the same class

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // Constructors here
private:
    std::vector<X> m_data; // X can be any (unsigned) integer type
};
```

I want the following code to work:

```
Foo f0;
Foo f1(1); // and/or f1({1})
Foo f2(1, 2); // and/or f2({1, 2})
Foo f3(1, 2, 3); // and/or f3({1, 2, 3})
Foo f4(1, 2, 3, 4); // ... and so on
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo f5(vec);
Foo f6(vec.begin(), vec.end());
std::list<std::size_t> list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo f7(list);
Foo f8(list.begin(), list.end());
std::any_iterable_container container = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo f9(container);
Foo f10(container.begin(), container.end());
// PS: I guess I only want containers/iterators that store individual
// values and not pairs (e.g., I don't want care about std::map
// because it does not make sense anyway).
```

So far I have tried to combine SFINAE, constructor overloading with all possible types, variadic templates, etc. Every time I fix one constructor case, others break down. Also, the code I write becomes very complex and hard to read. However, the problem seems quite simple and I guess I am just approaching it in a wrong way. Any suggestions on how to write the constructors (ideally in C++17), while also keeping the code as simple as possible, is more than welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure that the problem is as simple as you believe it is.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and its errors? Along with a description of what you want to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the class is defines as following:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    [..]

private:
    std::vector<T> m_data;
}
```

Let's break this task into sub-tasks:

**Construct from iterators**

```
template <class Iterator>
Foo (Iterator begin, Iterator end, typename Iterator::iterator_category * = 0)
    : m_data(begin, end);
```

We will fill in our `m_data` from `begin` and `end`.

The third parameter will make sure only `Iterator` types that declare `iterator_category` will match this prototype. Since this argument has a default value of `0` and is never specified, it serves a purpose only during the template deduction process. When the compiler checks if this is the right prototype, if the type `Iterator::iterator_category` doesn't exist, it will skip it. Since `iterator_category` is a must-have type for every standard iterator, it will work for them.

This c'tor will allow the following calls:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(vec.begin(), vec.end());
-- AND --
std::list<std::size_t> list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(list.begin(), list.end());
```

**Construct from container**

```
template <class Container>
Foo (const Container & container, decltype(std::begin(container))* = 0, decltype(std::end(container))* = 0)
    : m_data(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
```

We will fill our `m_data` from the given container. We iterate over it using `std::begin` and `std::end`, since they are more generic than their `.begin()` and `.end()` counterparts and support more types, e.g. primitive arrays.
This c'tor will allow the following calls:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(vec);
-- AND --
std::list<std::size_t> list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(list);
-- AND --
std::array<int,4> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(arr);
-- AND --
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Foo<int> f(arr);
```

**Construct from an initializer list**

```
template <class X>
Foo (std::initializer_list<X> && list)
    : m_data(std::begin(list), std::end(list));
```

*Note:* We take the list as an Rvalue-reference as it's usually the case, but we could also add a `Foo (const std::initializer_list<X> & list)` to support construction from Lvalues.

We fill in our `m_data` by iterating over the list once again. And this c'tor will support:

```
Foo<int> f1({1});
Foo<int> f2({1, 2});
Foo<int> f3({1, 2, 3});
Foo<int> f4({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

**Constructor from variable number of arguments**

```
template <class ... X>
Foo (X ... args) {
    int dummy[sizeof...(args)] = { (m_data.push_back(args), 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
}
```

Here, filling in the data into the container is a bit trickier. We use parameter expansion to unpack and push each of the arguments. This c'tor allows us to call:

```
Foo<int> f1(1);
Foo<int> f2(1, 2);
Foo<int> f3(1, 2, 3);
Foo<int> f4(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

**Entire class**

The final result is quite nice:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo () {
    std::cout << "Default" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class ... X>
  Foo (X ... args) {
    int dummy[sizeof...(args)] = { (m_data.push_back(args), 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
    std::cout << "VA-args" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class X>
  Foo (std::initializer_list<X> && list)
      : m_data(std::begin(list), std::end(list)) {
    std::cout << "Initializer" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class Container>
  Foo (const Container & container, decltype(std::begin(container))* = 0, decltype(std::end(container))* = 0)
      : m_data(std::begin(container), std::end(container)) {
    std::cout << "Container" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class Iterator>
  Foo (Iterator first, Iterator last, typename Iterator::iterator_category * = 0)
      : m_data(first, last) {
    std::cout << "Iterators" << std::endl;
  }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_data;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer my friend. I have to admit that the syntax of the `Foo(first, last, <check>)` confuses me a bit (I don't really understand it). Also, I realised that it does not work with `std::array` (although the question does not ask for `std::array`). Is this because the iterator of `std::array` is just a pointer? Thank you!

Comment: @AstrOne, I added some more information about the third parameter, and an example for `std::array` and primitive arrays, since it works for them as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. All answers in combination with some extra reading I did helped me a lot to understand how code like this works. While all answers are quite good I really appreciate everybody's help, I decided to accept your answer due to additional details you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to implement `f1`-`f4` (which seem to take a variable number of arguments of a known type `T` that is not a container or iterator) ist this:

```
template<typename... Args>
Foo(T arg, Args... args) {...}
```

As this constructor takes at least 1 argument, there is no ambiguity with the default constructor `f0`. As the first argument is of type `T`, there is no ambiguity with the following constructors.

If you want to treat `std::vector` and `std::list` differently than other containers, you can create a partly specialized helper template to check if an argument is an instance of a given template:

```
template<typename>
struct is_vector  : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Allocator>>  : std::true_type {};
```

And use it like this to implement `f5` and `f7`:

```
template<typename T, Constraint = typename std::enable_if<is_vector<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, void>::type>
Foo(T arg) {...}
```

By testing for the respective iterator types of `std::vector` and `std::list` you can implement `f6` and `f8` in the same way.

You can check for the presence of member functions `begin()` and `end()` to implement `f9` (I suppose) like this:

```
template<typename T>
Foo(T arg, decltype(arg.begin())* = 0, decltype(arg.end())* = 0)  {...}
```

However, you'll have to explicitly disable this constructor for `std::vector` and `std::list` using the helper templates you created to avoid ambiguity.

To check if an argument is some iterator to implement `f10`, you can use `std::iterator_traits`:

```
template<typename T, typename Constraint = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>
Foo(T begin, T end)  {...}
```

Again, you'll have to explicitly disable this constructor for the iterator types of `std::vector` and `std::list`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer my friend. If I only define the constructor with the signature `template<..stuff..> Foo(T begin, T end)`, the following code will fail: `Foo(1, 2)`. The compiler will give an additional error (besides the expected one): `no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<int>`. Is this because the `std::iterator_traits` are not SFINAE-friendy?

Comment: @AstrOne I'm not sure I understand. The `Foo(T begin, T end)` constructor is explicitly designed to only take iterators. It is supposed to fail for type `int`. The additional error you are getting simply explains why the compiler was unable to call this candidate constructor with two arguments of type `int`, i.e. because `std::iterator_traits` of course doesn't work with `int` (which is the point).

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to define the class like this:

```
template <typename X>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { };

  Foo(initializer_list<int> l) :m_data(l) { };

  template<typename container>
  Foo(container const & c) :m_data(c.begin(), c.end()) {};

  template<typename iterator>
  Foo(iterator begin, iterator end) :m_data(begin, end) { };
private:
  std::vector<X> m_data;
};
```

Where:

`Foo()` is the default (non-parametric) constructor.

`Foo(initializer_list<int> l)` accepts a list like  `{1, 2, 3}`.

`Foo(container const & c)` accepts any container that supports `begin` and `end` iterators.

`Foo(iterator begin, iterator end)` initializes the class with `begin` and `end` iterators.

Usage:

```
  Foo<int> f0;
  Foo<int> f1({1});
  Foo<int> f2({1, 2});
  Foo<int> f3({1, 2, 3});
  Foo<int> f4({1, 2, 3, 4});
  std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  Foo<int> f5(vec);
  Foo<int> f6(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  std::list<size_t> list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  Foo<size_t> f7(list);
  Foo<size_t> f8(list.begin(), list.end());
  set<unsigned> container = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  Foo<unsigned> f9(container);
  Foo<unsigned> f10(container.begin(), container.end());
```